# Updating a Rails model's attributes through mongoid using normal persistence methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, persistence

I have been chasing an issue down for a while now, and still cannot figure out what's happening. I am unable to edit documents made from my gem through normal persistence methods, like `update` or even just editing attributes and calling `save`.

For example, calling:

`Scram::Policy.where(id: a.id).first.update!(priority: 12345)`

Will not work at all (there are no errors, but the document has not updated). But the following will work fine:

`Scram::Policy.collection.find( { "_id" => a.id } ).update_one(  { "$set" => {"priority" => 12345}})`

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Calling update and save on any other model works fine. The document in question is from my gem: https://github.com/skreem/scram/blob/master/lib/scram/app/models/policy.rb

I cannot edit its embedded documents either (targets). I have tried removing the `store_in` macro, and specifying exactly what class to use using `inverse_of` and `class_name` in a fake app to reimplement these classes: https://github.com/skreem/scram-implementation/blob/master/lib/scram/lib/scram/app/models/policy.rb

I've tried reimplementing the entire gem into a clean fake rails application: https://github.com/skreem/scram-implementation

Running these in rails console demonstrates how updating does not work:
https://gist.github.com/skreem/c70f9ddcc269e78015dd31c92917fafa

Is this an issue with mongoid concerning embedded documents, or is there some small intricacy I am missing in my code?

**EDIT:**
The issue continues if you run `irb` from the root of my gem (scram) and then run the following:

```
require "scram.rb"
Mongoid.load!('./spec/config/mongoid.yml', :test)

Scram::Policy.first.update!(priority: 32) #=> doesn't update the document at all

Scram::Policy.where(id: "58af256f366a3536f0d54a61").update(priority: 322) #=> works just fine
```

Oddly enough, the following doesn't work:
`Scram::Policy.where(id: "58af256f366a3536f0d54a61").first.update(priority: 322)`

It seems like `first` isn't retrieving what I want. Doing an equality comparison shows that the first document is equal to the first returned by the `where` query.

Answer (score 0):

Well. As it turns out, you cannot call a field `collection_name` or else mongoid will ensure bad things happen to you. Just renaming the field solved all my issues. Here's the code within mongoid that was responsible for the collision: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/persistence_context.rb#L82

Here's the commit within my gem that fixed my issue: https://github.com/skreem/scram/commit/25995e955c235b24ac86d389dca59996fc60d822

**Edit:**

Make sure to update your Mongoid version if you have dealt with this issue and did not get any warnings! After creating an issue on the mongoid issue tracker, PersistenceContext was added to a list of prohibited methods. Now, attempting to use `collection_name` or `collection` as a field will cause mongoid to spit out a couple of warnings.

Fix commit: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/commit/6831518193321d2cb1642512432a19ec91f4b56d